# Change text colour in a TextBox upon condition

Tags: .net, vb.net, text, colors, richtextbox

I need to change the colour of one word in a rich text box when the text is equal to something, so for example if the user enters "Pink" the text will be pink but only the word pink.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: If you're talking Winforms, you can select a part of your textbox's text and apply change to the selection.

Answer (score 3):

As stated by @Kilazur in his/her comment you need to select the words and set the `SelectionColor`.

Here's an example:

```vb
Dim word As String = "word"
Dim index As Integer = Me.RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word)

Do While (index > -1)
    Me.RichTextBox1.Select(index, word.Length)
    Me.RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Pink
    index = Me.RichTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(word, (index + word.Length))
Loop
```

Comment: Your code will check only for one color, so  if more colors ware entered it will not give a better solution.

Comment: My English is not good so i don't know how to explain it, so i make a try. 1. You have to specify where this code have to be applied. 2. it will not give the complete solution for the question

Comment: @Sample I'm not here to judge your English. 1.) No I don't. If that was a part of the problem and/or stated in the question I would have. It's not. 2.) The key point of OPs question is how to *"change the colour of one word in a rich text box"*. My answer shows how.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SelectionColor property after selecting the text you are interested in.

You can look for the text whenever you like but the TextChanged event seems like a good time to do it (although if you have a lot of text it might be slow)

```
Private Sub RichTextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    FindWords(RichTextBox1, "Pink", Color.Pink)
End Sub

Private Sub FindWords(rtb As RichTextBox, word As String, wordColour As Color)
    'store the selection before any change was made so we can set it back later
    Dim selectionStartBefore As Integer = rtb.SelectionStart
    Dim selectionLengthBefore As Integer = rtb.SelectionLength

    Dim selection As Integer
    'loop through finding any words that match
    selection = rtb.Text.IndexOf(word)
    Do While selection >= 0
        rtb.SelectionStart = selection
        rtb.SelectionLength = word.Length
        rtb.SelectionColor = wordColour
        selection = rtb.Text.IndexOf(word, selection + word.Length)
    Loop

    'put the selection back to what it was
    rtb.SelectionStart = selectionStartBefore
    rtb.SelectionLength = selectionLengthBefore
    rtb.SelectionColor = rtb.ForeColor
End Sub
```